# is there a way to run a remote shell script on AWS MySql/Aurora that references sql remote files

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying to run an init script on a AWS MySQL database, I have been able to run the same script on a local instance of MySQL but not when attempting it on a remote instance. This is the command I run, from the directory that has both the shell script and sql resource files:

> mysql -u user -p -h endpoint123.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 <
>   create_database.sh

And after entering in my password get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 15: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near [line referencing SQL files]

Basically the script references local sql files that are also needed for the setup to complete. As far as I know, it is not possible to copy these files over to the AWS RDS machine. Is there any way to solve this so the shell script can run properly? Either by copying the files over or by running the shell script remotely? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the shell script as input to the `mysql` client. The `mysql` client can't parse shell scripts, it only understands .sql files. I would guess you need to modify your shell script to execute against the remote Aurora instance. I expect the shell script to run `mysql`, and it needs your `-h` option to specify a remote instance.

Comment: can you post the summary of what you are exactly trying to achieve here, cause mysql client only understand sql files

Comment: I now realize what I'm trying to do is needing to pipe the sql scripts that the shell script references into the mysql table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to feed in the output of your shell script to mysql. The syntax you are using is for executing a mysql (sql) script and NOT the output of a shell script. You would need to do something like this:

```
./script.sh | mysql -u abc -p -e
```

OR, in two phases:

```
./script.sh > out.sql  // To verify that the generated statements are correct
mysql -u abc -p -e < sql
```